# Is there a way to repair the audio of an Xbox 360?

Tags: xbox-360, audio-hardware

My Xbox 360 has serious audio issues.  Whenever I start it up I get a persistent crackling noise.

I've tried two different HDMI cables so my guess is that there is something wrong internally.  Does anyone here know if there's anything I can do on the inside of the machine to repair w/e the issue may be?

Comment: have you tried different HDMI ports on the TV?

Comment: There is only one HDMI port on the TV.

Comment: Does the crackling noise change when you nudge the cable while the console's on? Have you tried using the SCART/AVI cable that comes with the console by default?

Comment: Duplicate: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/63803/xbox-360s-to-tv-with-hdmi-suddenly-creating-static

Comment: @user70019 did the audio ever work well on the TV or is it new?

Comment: Different screen to test?

Comment: Does this thread belong here?

Answer (score 1):

Try running the sound through the digital optical audio and see if the problem persists.  I personally believe digital optical offers better sound fidelity.

Answer (score 0):

Check your connections and make sure the end of the hdmi and power cord isn't damaged and if that doesn't fix it or if theres nothing wrong then see if you can look inside your xbox 360 and see if its faulty wiring...

Comment: It is not damaged.  I have tried another HDMI cord that I used for a PS3 and another TV and it still doesn't work.  Do you know what kinds of things I would look for on the inside of the machine?

Comment: Have you tried the original cables?